# Service to sending location every minute, even if app is in background or system is rebooted

Tags: android, service, androidx

I need to create an app to track the user location. The location must be sent to server every one minute (delays arent problems). But I'm having many troubles to set up a task/service that last forever (even if I close my app or reboot the system)

*get the "last location" isn't the problem, the only problem is having a task/service, that runs "forever")

I tried to use Service. But android, since Marshmallow(I guess) version, can kill background Apps and Services anytime(Its a feature to avoid many app creating background services/tasks and consuming too much battery and memory).

Now I'm trying to use the new androidx "Worker" since i'd like to build an app with minSdk=16 and the current maxSdk(29).But now i'm facing two problems:
- The Worker cant run for more than 10 minutes (so I cant create a Worker that last forever).
- I could create a PeriodicWorkRequest, but the min time to re-schedule a Worker is 15 minutes (I need to send the location every one minute).

I tried to use OneTimeWorkRequest and re-scheduling itself, but its not works after a system reboot.

### Any ideas/solutions?

First schedule in the main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(
            OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkerTest::class.java).build()
        )
    }
}
```

the Worker (re-scheduling itself at the init of "doWork", with the one minute delay):

```
public class WorkerTest(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(
            OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(this::class.java).setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
        )

        //TODO get and send location

        return Result.success()
    }

}
```

Comment: "Any ideas/solutions?" -- build your own version of Android, where you relax its consumer restrictions. Other than that, use a foreground service with an `AlarmManager`-based "heartbeat" and deal with the occasional downtime when your process is terminated while the device is in Doze mode.

Comment: "Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted." (From the given doc)

Comment: Yes, which is why you need to re-register them on a reboot.

Comment: "Build your own version of Android" it's like to say "buy a new car" when your car runs out gas. How could I force users to download a specific version of Android to run the application?

Comment: @CommonsWare. Does "AlarmManager" works fine in all Android versions? (At least (16~~29)?

Comment: Use [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) for long running task

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology ForegroundService run after kill app and after reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager and run every minute to send your request to the server.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: "Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted." (From the given doc)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will tell you an idea:

1.Run your service on foreground/background: You can use a foreground service, this service is intended to run always, it is attached to a notification bar and if the user dismisses the notification the service will die, android will never let you run a service forever if the user is not aware of it.

2.Run your service after a Reboot: In order to run this service after a reboot, you will need to use a broadcast receiver for that system event. So when the reboot finishes you need to call your foreground service.

This is the road map that you have to follow. Remember that you will need user permissions for the location updates. And Depending on the SDK version the code, methods, and special needs on each one will be different.

Comment: Step one is a big problem. The users arent very smart, they will dismiss the notification and kill the service

Comment: I know bro,  that's the problem, however, It's the only option. Maybe you can put a good message on your notification and tell the user how your app works and why it needs that notification.